# How set xmlns prefix in deserialization class for the root element

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I used [xmltocsharp site](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) to create the class helper to deserialize an specific XML, but is not working, and the problem is in the root element. This is the root element (RESP_HDR and RESP_BODY were collapsed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SII:RESPUESTA xmlns:SII="http://www.sii.cl/XMLSchema">
    + <SII:RESP_HDR>
    + <SII:RESP_BODY>
</SII:RESPUESTA>
```

And this is the root element class generated by [xmltocsharp site](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/):

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "RESPUESTA", Namespace = "http://www.sii.cl/XMLSchema")]
public class RESPUESTA
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "RESP_HDR", Namespace = "http://www.sii.cl/XMLSchema")]
    public RESP_HDR RESP_HDR { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "RESP_BODY", Namespace = "http://www.sii.cl/XMLSchema")]
    public RESP_BODY RESP_BODY { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "SII", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string SII { get; set; }
}
```

The issue is that the class fails to deserialize a XML like the showed before, but success with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RESPUESTA xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SII="http://www.sii.cl/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.sii.cl/XMLSchema">
    + <SII:RESP_HDR>
    + <SII:RESP_BODY>
</RESPUESTA>
```

The difference is in the namespaces, even if a create the object and serialize it, this will be the result. So, what should be changed in the class to make it work with the original XML?

**UPDATE:**

---

Looking closer I found the really issue, is in the root element still, but I notice the missing xmlns prefix in the root tag, how can I set it in the helper class?

**EDIT:**

---

This is an XML sample from the service response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SII:RESPUESTA xmlns:SII="http://www.sii.cl/XMLSchema">
    <SII:RESP_HDR>
        <SII:ESTADO>0</SII:ESTADO>
        <SII:GLOSA/>
    </SII:RESP_HDR>
    <SII:RESP_BODY>
        <DATOS_CONSULTA>
            <RUT>80182144-3</RUT>
            <TIPO_CONSULTA>DEUDOR</TIPO_CONSULTA>
            <DESDE_DDMMAAAA>01042017</DESDE_DDMMAAAA>
            <HASTA_DDMMAAAA>01052017</HASTA_DDMMAAAA>
        </DATOS_CONSULTA>
        <CESION>
            <VENDEDOR>11455447-9</VENDEDOR>
            <ESTADO_CESION>Cesion Vigente</ESTADO_CESION>
            <DEUDOR>80182144-3</DEUDOR>
            <MAIL_DEUDOR/>
            <TIPO_DOC>33</TIPO_DOC>
            <NOMBRE_DOC>Factura Electronica</NOMBRE_DOC>
            <FOLIO_DOC>107</FOLIO_DOC>
            <FCH_EMIS_DTE>2017-04-04</FCH_EMIS_DTE>
            <MNT_TOTAL>3324860</MNT_TOTAL>
            <CEDENTE>11455447-9</CEDENTE>
            <RZ_CEDENTE>JHON DOE</RZ_CEDENTE>
            <MAIL_CEDENTE>jjdoe@gmail.com</MAIL_CEDENTE>
            <CESIONARIO>762327129-7</CESIONARIO>
            <RZ_CESIONARIO>capital sa</RZ_CESIONARIO>
            <MAIL_CESIONARIO>xcap@capital.com</MAIL_CESIONARIO>
            <FCH_CESION>2017-04-05 13:15</FCH_CESION>
            <MNT_CESION>3324860</MNT_CESION>
            <FCH_VENCIMIENTO>2017-06-04</FCH_VENCIMIENTO>
        </CESION>
        <CESION>
            <VENDEDOR>11455447-9</VENDEDOR>
            <ESTADO_CESION>Cesion Vigente</ESTADO_CESION>
            <DEUDOR>80182144-3</DEUDOR>
            <MAIL_DEUDOR/>
            <TIPO_DOC>33</TIPO_DOC>
            <NOMBRE_DOC>Factura Electronica</NOMBRE_DOC>
            <FOLIO_DOC>34</FOLIO_DOC>
            <FCH_EMIS_DTE>2017-03-01</FCH_EMIS_DTE>
            <MNT_TOTAL>1725500</MNT_TOTAL>
            <CEDENTE>11455447-9</CEDENTE>
            <RZ_CEDENTE>JOE DOE</RZ_CEDENTE>
            <MAIL_CEDENTE>jd@gmail.com</MAIL_CEDENTE>
            <CESIONARIO>762327129-7</CESIONARIO>
            <RZ_CESIONARIO>Capital S.A.</RZ_CESIONARIO>
            <MAIL_CESIONARIO>jcap@capital.com</MAIL_CESIONARIO>
            <FCH_CESION>2017-04-05 17:27</FCH_CESION>
            <MNT_CESION>1725500</MNT_CESION>
            <FCH_VENCIMIENTO>2017-03-01</FCH_VENCIMIENTO>
        </CESION>
    </SII:RESP_BODY>
</SII:RESPUESTA>
```

Comment: Both XML are identical. They have the same element names and the same namespaces. The namespace prefixes are irrelevant.

Comment: Still not working, the only way so far that I can make it work is modifying the obtained XML, add the prefix SII to the tag `RESPUESTA` and add the rest of the namespaces, then deserialize this XML.

Comment: I meant "remove" the prefix SII from the tag `RESPUESTA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the only way that I can make it work is with a really ugly solution, **this should not be considered as an answer to the problem!!**.

```
//Query service to obtain XML response
string xmlResponse = siiClient.QueryDocuments(documentsRequest);

//Replace RESPUESTA tags in the XML response, remove the prefix SII
var replacedXML = xmlResponse .Replace("SII:RESPUESTA", "RESPUESTA" );

//Load XML string into XmlDocument
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(replacedXML);

//Add missing namespaces
xDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
xDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
xDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.sii.cl/XMLSchema");

//Now deserialization will work
var documentResponse = xDoc.ParseXML<RESPUESTA>();
```

The ideal solution will take the XML Response and deserialize it directly without any preprocessing like:

```
//Query service to obtain XML response
string xmlResponse = siiClient.QueryDocuments(documentsRequest);

//ParseXML is an extension method, it can handle an string or an XmlDocument
var documentResponse = xmlResponse.ParseXML<RESPUESTA>();
```

Note: ParseXML is based on [@Damian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19613934/553029)

Comment: I just added more details to the question and also a comment to your answer, thank you for your attention.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov You're correct it is valid XML either way, however you often encounter custom written XML validation which will insist the XML elements are structured a certain way, it's what led me here, some idiot insisting I add the prefix to the root element :|  This answer is terrible btw, just don't do this.

Comment: @tonyenkiducx - I agree. Customers often insist on a particular format. I'm trying to explain to them, waving the xml standard... not helps.

Comment: I figured out what is most likely the issues anyway, related to not posting all your code ;)  Your serializer might be missing the hints for the namespace so no prefix is added, or you might be adding a blank root attribute to your serializer(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49556390/c-sharp-serializer-not-adding-prefix-to-root-element)

Answer (score 0):

I took your xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SII:RESPUESTA xmlns:SII="http://www.sii.cl/XMLSchema">
  <SII:RESP_HDR/>
  <SII:RESP_BODY/>
</SII:RESPUESTA>
```

I took you class:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "RESPUESTA", Namespace = "http://www.sii.cl/XMLSchema")]
public class RESPUESTA
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "RESP_HDR", Namespace = "http://www.sii.cl/XMLSchema")]
    public RESP_HDR RESP_HDR { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "RESP_BODY", Namespace = "http://www.sii.cl/XMLSchema")]
    public RESP_BODY RESP_BODY { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "SII", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string SII { get; set; }
}
public class RESP_HDR { }
public class RESP_BODY { }
```

Just added two empty class stub.

Try `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`:

```
RESPUESTA respuesta;

var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RESPUESTA));

using (var fs = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Open))
    respuesta = (RESPUESTA)xs.Deserialize(fs);
```

It works! I don't understand how and why it does not work for you.

Comment: Petrov, I never mentioned having an error trying to deserialize, is just that the result is an empty object, just like the one you get. I have added an XML sample, from the service response, maybe you can try once more. Remember that I generate the class in http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/