# C# serializer not adding prefix to root element

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Seen lots of people with this same issue and no answers anywhere, so answering it myself here;

When serializing an XML class that should have a prefix attached to it, the prefix is missing.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Preadvice", Namespace = "http://www.wibble.com/PreadviceRequest")]
public class Preadvice
{
}

var XMLNameSpaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
XMLNameSpaces.Add("isd", "http://www.wibble.com/PreadviceRequest");
```

And this is my serializing method;

```
public static string SerializeStandardObject<T>(T obj, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns, XmlAttributeOverrides xao, XmlRootAttribute xra)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), (xao == null ? new XmlAttributeOverrides() : xao), new Type[] { obj.GetType() }, (xra == null ? new XmlRootAttribute(obj.GetType().Name) : xra), "");

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (System.Xml.XmlTextWriter writer = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, obj, (ns == null ? new XmlSerializerNamespaces() : ns));
        }
        return sw.ToString();
    }
}
```

This produces;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Preadvice xmlns:isd="http://www.wibble.com/PreadviceRequest">
</Preadvice>
```

Which is missing the prefix, it should look like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<isd:Preadvice xmlns:isd="http://www.wibble.com/PreadviceRequest">
</isd:Preadvice>
```

Comment: The problem here is simply your use of `new XmlRootAttribute(obj.GetType().Name)`. 
This does exactly what you asked: it uses an element name of `obj.GetType().Name`, but **in the default/root namespace**. If you didn't want the default/root namespace: you need to tell it which namespace you *did* want, perhaps using reflection to check for a pre-existing attribute. However - see my comment on your answer: casually using `new XmlSerializer(...)` when *specifying attribute overrides* is a recipe for disaster; you *cannot* do that casually.

Answer (score 0):

If your serializer includes an xmlrootattribute when it is created, it doesn't apply namespaces you have specified manually, and therefore misses the "isd" tag off the first element.  The easiest fix is to remove the xmlrootattribute;

```
public static string SerializeStandardObject<T>(T obj, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (System.Xml.XmlTextWriter writer = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, obj, (ns == null ? new XmlSerializerNamespaces() : ns));
        }
        return sw.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a **really really** bad idea; I cannot express how bad an idea this is; this will leak assemblies like crazy - and they can *never* be collected. Eventually you *will* get OOMs. You have to be **really, really** careful when constructing `XmlSerializer` passing in an `XmlAttributeOverrides` instance. I urge you to reconsider this code, ideally caching the generated `XmlSerializer` instance (aka `serializer`) per whatever the unique context is here.

Comment: I've been running this serializer for some time now, and I've never had an OOM?  The xmlattributeoverride doesn't seem to linger for long after I dispose of it either.  Is there some other condition that stops GC from picking it up?

Comment: the problem isn't due to `XmlAttributeOverride` not being collected; it is simply part of how XmlSerializer works - it generates and compiles a new assembly *every time*. For simple scenario (like `new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo))` it has an inbuilt cache to prevent this problem, but when you use `XmlAttributeOverrides`, it *cannot do this*. And assemblies, once loaded, cannot be unloaded from an app-domain.

Comment: And because I don't expect you to blindly take my word for it: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/774bf78db122d36230d4f968a8c970b2 - you can see how it is bleeding assemblies; note that they will **never** be collected, and also note that it is **much, much** slower  - that's because it is generating each time rather than reusing

Comment: I agree it's faster in the circumstances you have on your github, however you have two completely different results from your code.  How would you add the prefix without an override?  *EDIT* Just realised I said the wrong thing, how would you add the overrides?

Comment: if I didn't have different results, there wouldn't be any point using `XmlAttributeOverrides` in the first place... but as for adding the prefix without an override: you can specify the namespace in all of the relevant attributes; the *namespace alias* (`isd` in your example) is done via `XmlSerializerNamespaces` which you already have in the code in the question, and which works fine.

Comment: if you're asking "how can you do this without it being a problem": you need to figure out some unique identifier for the different contexts, and **cache** an `XmlSerializer` per unique combination, only generating a new one when there isn't one already. As long as you aren't constantly calling `new XmlSerializer(...config...)` you will be fine.

Comment: Ahhah, I see what you mean now.  I am still perplexed how this code is working on our live service, it's been switched on and processing 4-5000 orders a day since November 12th and it's currently using 23MB of ram.  I might have to run a performance profile on it and see how it's managing to cope.

Comment: We're using a plugin system and it seems to be mitigating the issue on the live code...  Have updated the example to reflect your advice though, totally agree!